# Drupal-6: Why won't this node save?

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have constructed a set of nodes. After running them through `node_save()`, I get back an `nid`, and I can navigate to the page for that node, but they are empty. (No data is shown for any of the fields.)

When I go to the edit url for that node, I get this error message:

> warning: call_user_func_array()
>   [function.call-user-func-array]: First
>   argument is expected to be a valid
>   callback, 'Bout_node_form' was given
>   in
>   /home/odp/public_html/includes/form.inc
>   on line 367.

Here is the `print_r()` of one node I am trying to save:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => Bout
    [name] => Gary Oak
    [title] => Bout - 0
    [promote] => 1
    [comment] => 2
    [revision] => 
    [format] => 0
    [status] => 0
    [field_weapon] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => foil
                )

        )

    [field_fencer] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 3
                )

        )

    [field_touches_scored] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 4
                )

        )

    [field_meet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nid] => Drew
                )

        )

    [field_round] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

    [field_legacy_bout] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => no
                )

        )

    [teaser] => 
    [uid] => 1
    [created] => 1262732370
    [validated] => 1
)
```

These nodes have all been run though `node_validate()`, and presumably that would have caught some errors. Also, this node is missing required taxonomy, but that isn't causing any error messages, either.

This is how `node_validate()` was called:

```
function preview_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    $nodes_to_save = construct_nodes();

    foreach ($nodes_to_save as $node) {
        node_validate($node, $form);
        if ($errors = form_get_errors()) {
            form_set_error('', t('Validation error. No nodes saved.'));
        }
    }

    $_SESSION[CONSTRUCTED_KEY] = $nodes_to_save;
}
```

This is where the error is coming from, in the core file `includes/form.inc`:

```
  // If $callback was returned by a hook_forms() implementation, call it.
  // Otherwise, call the function named after the form id.
  $form = call_user_func_array(isset($callback) ? $callback : $form_id, $args);
```

The node shows up in the `node` table, but not the `content_type_bout` table.

This is the construct_nodes() function:

```
function construct_nodes() {
    global $user;
    $file = unserialize($_SESSION[FILE_KEY]);

    $count = 0;         // how many nodes have been created?
    $success = TRUE;    // have all the nodes thus far validated?
    foreach ($file->parsed as $node) {
        $odp = new StdClass();
        $odp->type = $_SESSION[NODE_TYPE_KEY];

        if (! in_array('name', $file->matched_keys)) {
            $odp->name = $user->name;
        }

        if (! in_array('title', $file->matched_keys)) {
            $odp->title = sprintf("%s - %s", $_SESSION[NODE_TYPE_KEY], $count);
        }

        $node_type_default = variable_get('node_options_'. $_SESSION[NODE_TYPE_KEY], array('status', 'promote')); //copied from blogapi module

        $odp->promote = in_array('promote', $node_type_default);
        $odp->comment = variable_get('comment_'. $_SESSION[NODE_TYPE_KEY], 2);
        $odp->revision = in_array('revision', $node_type_default);
        $odp->format = FILTER_FORMAT_DEFAULT;
        $odp->status = CTN_DEFAULT_PUBLISHED;

        // this makes the assumption that the field arrays will always have only one item
        // doesn't handle taxonomy
        foreach ($node as $field => $value) { // $field => value:                           [Touches scored] => 5
            $node_key = $file->matched_keys[$field]; // $node_key will be something like:   "field_meet" or "vid:4"
            $vid = vidOfTaxKey($node_key);
            if ($vid == NULL) {
                $valTypes = $_SESSION[SAMPLE_NODE_KEY]->$node_key; // like:     [0] => Array ( [uid] => 3 )
                $valType = array_keys($valTypes[0]);
                $odp->$node_key = array(array($valType[0] => $value));
            }
        }

        $to_save[] = $odp;
        $count++;
        unset($submitted_odp);
    }
    return $to_save;
}
```

`bout` is a CCK-defined content type. Using the human name "Bout" for the type instead of the internal code name `bout` was, I believe, a source of error.

Comment: how did you call node_validate()

Comment: please show what in line 367 is

Comment: could i see your `construct_nodes()`?

Comment: @ax added that function above

Comment: Where is the nodetype defined?

Comment: @Macros: exactly / +1 - see my answer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009830/drupal-6-why-wont-this-node-save/2139579#2139579 >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. where is this custom content type defined? in a [custom module](http://drupal.org/node/231019), or via *Administer > Content > Content types > Add content type*? is it defined at all? if not, then no wonder you get this error: how is Drupal supposed to know what this content type is composed of and how to render its view and edit forms? try defining it, either way.
2. custom content (node) type names (`[type] => Bout`) [*must contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores*](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/drupal/modules/node/content_types.inc?revision=1.110&view=markup#l109). try changing `Bout` to `bout`.

see also [How do I create a node from a cron job in drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88566/how-do-i-create-a-node-from-a-cron-job-in-drupal) and http://drupal.org/node/178506#comment-895418 (the whole thread).

Comment: It looks like #2 was the answer, but I haven't quite solved this issue entirely... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151015/drupal-6-why-cant-a-post-be-referenced

Comment: please don't ask a new question for the same problem, but edit your question here to clearly state the problem as you are understanding  it so far. the other question will be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$new_blognode = new stdClass();
$new_blognode->type = 'blog';
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$output .= drupal_get_form('blog_node_form', $new_blognode);
?>
```

note that you should change this to your needs

Comment: I'm not trying to alter the way the node is displayed or edited - I just want to save it and have it work properly, just like a node that wasn't created programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

$node['type']='bout'; NOT $node['type']='Bout';

Confirm that you are not struck with simple caps problem.