# Drupal-6: Why can't a post be referenced?

Tags: php, drupal-6

I am making nodes programmatically. One node field is a `nid` reference to a node of type `Meet`. I have set these attributes to a real node of type Meet. However, when I run this node object through `node_validate()`, I get an error:

> Meet: this post can't be referenced.

Why does this happen? Here is the node object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => bout
    [name] => Gary Oak
    [promote] => 
    [comment] => 2
    [revision] => 
    [format] => 0
    [status] => 0
    [title] => the title 4
    [uid] => 4
    [field_touches_scored] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 4
                )

        )

    [field_touches_received] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 5
                )

        )

    [field_meet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nid] => 2583
                )

        )

    [field_round] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

    [field_legacy_bout] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 0
                )

        )

    [field_weapon] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => saber
                )

        )

)
```

Also, I'm not really sure what's going on with the error reporting. This is my function to validate the nodes:

```
$nodes_to_save = construct_nodes();

foreach ($nodes_to_save as $node) {
    node_validate($node, $form);
    if ($errors = form_get_errors()) {
        form_set_error('', t('Validation error. No nodes saved.'));
    }
}
```

I would expect that if any error were generated by `node_validate()`, the additional `form_set_error()` call would be fired. However, I get only one error, which is the one referenced above. Am I misunderstanding these functions?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009830/drupal-6-why-wont-this-node-save . please edit the original question instead of posting a slightly modified new one.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate... the "post can't be referenced" issue occurs throughout my Drupal installation, and this is just one example of it. I am interested in what that error message means.

Comment: i think it is the same issue: that you don't have your "bout" nodetype defined anywhere (you didn't answer our questions in the original post). so please update the original question with you findings (you can also cut some code, like the one requested by me).